# Three durations or increment date 3 duration using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner. Make increment date when input duration is 3.

Example

```
<input id="startdate" name="startdate">
```

With a current value of **1/1/2017**.

Output needs to be:

```
1/1/2017
2/1/2017
3/1/2017
```

or

```
1-1-2017 
2-1-2017 
3-1-2017
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <label>Enter Date:</label><input type="date" id="txtInput">
    <button type="button" onclick="getDates()">Submit</button>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function getDates() {
            var duration = 3;
            var selectDate = new Date($('#txtInput').val());
            var dateFormat = d3.timeFormat("%d-%m-%Y");
            var arrDates = [];
            var date = selectDate.getDate();
            for (var index = 0; index < duration; index++) {
               arrDates.push(dateFormat(new Date((new Date($('#txtInput').val())).setDate(date +(index)))));
            }
            alert(arrDates.join(','));
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your answered is very helpful. can I ask again. How to increment months using your answered?

Thank You. have a great day.

Comment: In above answer, months are increment automatically because we use setDate method. Ex. If you enter 31/12/2017 date then your increment 3 dates are 31/12/2017,1/1/2018,2/1/2018